# How to use right mouse click events in use-gesture/react

Tags: reactjs, draggable, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei, react-use-gesture

When I use bind function from the react-use-gesture on a mesh, then the mouse down events on the mesh are overridden by the bind event. And usegesture is only taking only left click events.

I tried adding mousedown events on mesh but it didn't work

Comment: I got the mouse right click events using the usegesture hook which handles multiple events at once.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work by using the button property on the event. In my case, I am using the `useGesture` hook, like this:

```js
const bind = useGesture({
  onMouseDown: (state: any) => {
    if (state.event.button === 2) {
      // right click behavior
    } else {
      // any other button
    }
  }
});
```

I couldn't find an example in their documentation, but I did find a part of the config called `pointer.buttons` [here](https://use-gesture.netlify.app/docs/options/#pointerbuttons) that can be used for the drag configuration. The docs mention that this allows the drag to be triggered by buttons other than the left click, and has a link to the [MDN Web Docs, MouseEvent: buttons property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/buttons). Since `useGesture` passes the event back in the state as `state.event`, we can then detect which mouse button was used by checking the value of `state.event.button`.

This is the list of possible button values:

```
0: No button or un-initialized
1: Primary button (usually the left button)
2: Secondary button (usually the right button) ⬅️
4: Auxiliary button (usually the mouse wheel button or middle button)
8: 4th button (typically the "Browser Back" button)
16 : 5th button (typically the "Browser Forward" button)
```